# window location not working javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having problem on single and double quote in window location in javascript. I have this data in my database `test's data` and i use this in window location like this :

```
function test(name){
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/test/tests.php?name="+ name;
}
```

this is my php code:

```
 $name = "test's data";
    echo '
        <button onclick="return test(\''. $name .'\')" class="btn btn-danger">TEST</button>
         ';
```

and if you check it in development tool it would be like:

```
<button onclick="return test('test's data')" class="btn btn-danger">TEST</button>
```

i know my error is the quotation in test('test's data'). How can i fix my quotations in function so it will redirect you to another page test.php?

Comment: By not using buttons! `echo '<a href="http://localhost/test/tests.php?name=' . url_encode($name) . '" class="btn btn-danger">TEST</a>';`.

Comment: Change `window.location.href = "http://localhost/test/tests.php?name="+ name;` to `window.location.href = "http://localhost/test/tests.php?name="+ encodeURIComponent(name);`

Comment: Or instead you can use document.location alternative to window.location.href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change $name to

```
$name = "test\'s data";
```

to escape the apostrophe.  Or better yet, use

```
$name = addslashes("test's data");
```

To escape all special characters.

Comment: thanks for all of your answers. this one is working @michael.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following:

```
document.location.replace(...);
```